# DecimalFormat applyPattern in Java not overriding the locale settings

Tags: java, internationalization, decimalformat

I'm trying to debug an issue involving `DecimalFormat#applyPattern(String)` in Java 1.6. The default locale is French so the decimal separator by default is ','. However, the pattern specifies applying a '.' to the decimal format instance which it doesn't seem to. I tried to debug into `applyPattern()` but couldn't see the variable values. I'm not really familiar with patterns and reg-ex's so I'm not sure if the issue is with the pattern or something else. Is it the pattern which is incorrect or there is some other issue with the code?

Here is the code snippet:

```
public class DecimalFormatTester
{
   static private final DecimalFormat doubleFormat = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance();

     static 
     {
       doubleFormat.applyPattern("############.00");
     }

  public static String toString(double value) 
  {
    synchronized (doubleFormat) 
    {
        return doubleFormat.format(value);
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a sample line of `Junit` code which fails:

```
assertEquals("String values aren't equal", "2179005635.00", DecimalFormatTester.toString(2.179005635E9));
```

Comment: What is wrong? Is it the pattern due to which it is failing?

Comment: Edit a question not a comment to add questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **`.`** in pattern **`############.00`** is a placeholder for the (currently set)  decimalCharacter.

If you want **`.`** as decimalcharacter then you additionally have to set
decimalCharacter, eg. by setting `Locale.US`

You could save your current locale, then set to `Locale.US`, then set back your saved `Locale`,
but make sure your app is not multi threaded.

You also could use

```
DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().setDecimalSeparator(".");
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to simply change the Locale to US before applying the pattern or is there a method on DecimalFormat to specify the decimalCharacter?

Comment: There is a method setDecimalSymbols but I have never used that, I would temporarily set the Locale to US, and afterward change it back

Comment: This worked for me in the static block:                                final DecimalFormatSymbols dcs = doubleFormat.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
        dcs.setDecimalSeparator('.');
        doubleFormat.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dcs);

Answer (score 1):

Change the Locale for the apropiate output. In anothe hand, you can use a custom [`DecimalFormatSymbols`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html).

```
###,###.###      123,456.789     en_US
###,###.###      123.456,789     de_DE
###,###.###      123 456,789     fr_FR
```

See more in [Locale-Sensitive Formatting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)

Comment: Thanks for the links, they were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In the pattern `############.00`, the '.' represents the decimal separator of your locale.

In your case I understand it's the french decimal separator, which is a ','.